# How to use ImageSlideshow and a label

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this library as slideshow:

[ImageSlideshow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow)

now,I want to add label over it but that show behind of image :

[image]

[image]

I cannot change position `label title` and `image slider`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can call label to front by

try this

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: yourlabel)
```

or use

```
yourimageslider.bringSubview(toFront: yourlabel)
```

or use

```
yourscrollviewName.bringSubview(toFront: yourlabel)
```

> You can send image view to the back by
>   or could use

```
self.yourscrollviewName.sendSubview(toBack: yourImagesliderName)
```

Comment: `yourimageslider.bringSubview(toFront: your label)` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront:subViewObj)
```

subViewObj might be your label, But subViewObj should be added some where in root view. Here the root view is self.view.